# I'm building a page that displays logged in user information that the user can update

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

```
The logged in user information should be displayed in a page called MyAccount.ejs

EJS Form:

<form action="MyAccount" method="post">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value=""required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" value="" required>
      </div>
<form action="/MyAccount.ejs" method="POST">
    <button class="btn update-btn fw-bold" type="button" style="width: 200px;"  name="edit">Update</button>
</form>
</div>
```

The second form tag is for a button that saves the changes

```
MyAccount GET Route:

    app.get('/MyAccount', (req, res) => {
  // Check if user is logged in
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    // Render MyAccount.ejs with user data
    res.render('MyAccount', { user: req.session.user });
  } else {
    // Redirect to login page
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});


MyAccount POST Route:

    app.post('/MyAccount', (req, res) => {
  // Check if user is logged in
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    // Update user data
    // ...
    res.send('Data updated successfully!');
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
});
```

The MyAccount.ejs displays fields such as name, email, phone number etc, of logged in users only.
The values are empty in the code and the browser, and my node code doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you added the `cookie-parser` package? Your code does not appear to use it directly, but it is probably pretty safe to assume that `req.session` _will_ be using cookies internally.

Comment: I added it and the pages are now rendered. But the information of logged in users is not being displayed.

Comment: Where, in your form, you mean? Well you have some of the field values set with _static_ values there, and others you set to an empty string ... If you want to see existing data in your form fields, then you need to _set_ it.

Comment: I don't want to set the data. The data, that should appear in the fields in the page, name, email, phone number, age, etc. , should be logged in users data. The value with "TestTest" and the other value are meant to be deleted, and instead only logged in users should be displayed.

Comment: Yes, you do. If you want specific data to "appear" in those fields, then you need to _set_ this data as the content of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

- You should not use nested forms in HTML or EJS. According to the HTML specification, nesting forms is not allowed. Each  tag in HTML should be a standalone entity and cannot contain another form. If you try to nest forms, the behavior is not well defined and may lead to unpredictable results across different browsers.

  If you are using two forms then you can separate them, and I see in your code that a button is added in a different form. You should remove the second form and add the button into the first form, then when you click the button, a post request will be sent as you expect.
- Another mistake is your Form Action in MyAccount.ejs and this is second form:

  In your form tag, the action attribute is set to "/MyAccount.ejs," but based on your routes, it seems like you want the form to submit to the `"/MyAccount"` route. Change the action attribute to match the route:
- The last mistake is in the Form Submission Button:

  In your form, the button type is set to `"button"` If you want the
  form to be submitted when the button is clicked, change the type to
  `"submit"`

  ```
  <button class="btn update-btn fw-bold" type="submit" style="width: 200px;" name="edit">Update</button>
  ```

With these changes, your form should now submit to the `"/MyAccount"` route when the "Update" button is clicked.